# How can I convert List<byte> to byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, list, c#-2.0, byte

Can I convert via a `for` loop?

Is there any better method to do it?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myListByte.Count ;i++)
 {
     myArryByte[i] = myListByte[i];
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible to switch to C# 3.0? If so, use `ToArray` method, if not, go with good old "create an array, copy values in foreach loop" approach

Comment: @Dyppl: ToArray is available for List<> in 2.0. Switching to 3.0 for this isn't necessary. Besides, one would not switch frameworks for a single convenience feature.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: you're right, I totally forgot about that and was sure that people refer to the LINQ extension method. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that List and IList have different methods and IList does not have ToArray()...

Comment: Personally, for working with binary data I would suggest `MemoryStream` over `List<byte>`. Then you can use `GetBuffer()` to access the ***oversized*** backing-buffer without an additional allocation; you just need to remember to only read `.Length` bytes from it ;p

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
myArryByte = myListByte.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
List<byte> bytes = ...;

byte[] bArrary = bytes.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the List object's [ToArray method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

```
byte[] arr = myListByte.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
private void convertByteArray()
{
    List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>() {2, 3, 4};
    byte[] byteArray = byteList.ToArray<byte>();
}
```